# Center element to full width with one element to the left

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I'm trying to left-align one element (button) and center on entire width another element (logo). The logo in the center is always shifted a little to the right. On desktop, I have to add text to the right of the button and it's very visible.

[image]

```css
.header-checkout-flow {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-checkout-flow .back-button .back-button-img {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  background: #000;
}

.header-checkout-flow .link-txt {
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-checkout-flow .site-logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.header-checkout-flow .site-logo img {}
```

```html
<div class="header-checkout-flow">
  <div class="back-button">
    <a class="back-button-img" href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/30x30" alt="Site Logo" />
    </a>
    <p class="link-txt">Back to the site</p>

  </div>
  <a href="#" rel="home" class="site-logo">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x80" alt="Site Logo" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `position: absolute;` (most likely also `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` for `.back-button` and `position: relative;` for your `.header-checkout-flow`.